# Formularios Reactivos Angular, valueChanges no capta el nuevo valor

Tags: formularios, angular, typescript, angular5, angular-directivas

Tengo un problemilla que llevo tiempo intentando resolver.

Tengo 3 inputs que interactuan entre si para calcular el precio con IVA y viceversa.

Os dejo un stackblitz para que podais verlo mejor. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szzcux)

El problema está, cuando escribo en el `precioCompra` el `[value]` de `precioCompraIva` debería de cambiar y no lo hace... O sea si lo hace, pero no lo consigo captar.

Alguien sabe decirme como solucionarlo? o porque ocurre?

Gracias de antemano

En el constructor estoy suscrito a valueChanges, para controlar los valores.

Como podeis observar, al escribir en `precioCompra`. El valor de `precioCompraIva` no cambia y viceversa tampoco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estás haciendo los cambios en la forma en el DOM. Para que el detector de cambios funcione bien, tenés que hacer los cambios en el objeto `Form` que creaste.

Adjunto tu ejemplo [editado en Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v7at5x).

Lo que estoy haciendo es que ya no se ingresa el valor en el HTML, sino que de allí sacamos los eventos de `(input)` para detectar el momento en el que el usuario ha ingresado algún caracter en la forma.

Ese evento dispara las funciones de cálculo correspondientes, y el cambio se hace en el objeto `Form` usando el método `setValue`.

```
this.datosFormulario.get('preciocompra')
  .setValue(this.calcularPrecioCompraIva());
```

Al usar `setValue` nos aseguramos que se dispare el detector de cambios.

Comment: acabo de tener un orgasmo :D, muchas gracias! era exactamente lo que necesitaba, además entendí por qué ocurre esto. Una cosita... estuve mirando el tema de eventos... y ví varios eventos como keyup, keypress, change, click, etc etc, pero el que usaste (input) que no lo vi, sabes de alguna web donde pueda encontrar estos eventos? ( soy newbie en progromacion :P ) , Gracias de nuevo!